# Apache Kylin - no average measure when creating a cube

Tags: hadoop, cube, kylin

I'm trying to add an average measure, but I can't find it in the available measures from the following dropdown list : [image: dropdown list of the available measures]
It does seem to be possible if we look at the page 12 from this page https://www.slideshare.net/YangLi43/design-cube-in-apache-kylin . Or the page 16 from this page https://www.slideshare.net/XuJiang2/kylin-hadoop-olap-engine .

Is it still possible to have an average measure in Kylin ? If so, how do we add one ?

Note : I use the version 1.6.0 of Kylin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Average measure is computed as SUM/COUNT. Kylin has SUM and COUNT measures. You could query by AVG() in SQL, it will translate to SUM/COUNT automatically in the backend.